# neovim map command strangeness

Tags: neovim, nmap

Using `neovim`. Since `hlsearch` is on, after the search and replace operation the strings are highlighted. Pressing `<C-l>` clears the highlight.

I have this keymap to convert a line to title caps:

```
map('n', 'tc', ':s/\\v<(.)(\\w*)/\\u\\1\\L\\2/g<cr><C-l>', default_opts)
```

The above works except for clearing the highlighting.

If I use from within `neovim`:

```
:nmap tc :s/\v<(.)(\w*)/\u\1\L\2/g<cr><C-l>
```

things work properly.

What is wrong with the earlier sequence?

Comment: I'll test more  but it looks odd to me that <c-l> clear the highlight. The `:noh` is there for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
:nmap tc :s/\v<(.)(\w*)/\u\1\L\2/g<cr>:noh<cr>
```

If you have a mapping that link `<C-l>` to `:noh` your solution rely on the recursivity of the mapping.

```
map('n', '<C-l>', ':noh<cr>', { noremap = false })
map('n', 'tc', ':s/\\v<(.)(\\w*)/\\u\\1\\L\\2/g<cr><C-l>', { noremap = false })
```

Comment: It works. I have defined `<c-l>` as `:set nohls<cr>`. My question is why it works one way and not the other?

Comment: I suspect that your `default_options` make the mapping non recursive and that in the second mapping the `<C-l>` is a pure redraw not including `:noh`.